# Why does this print a segmentation fault (core dumped) while reading a RAW file?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Can you tell me why does this particular code gives a segmentation fault? I had written this to read data from a RAW file and to put it in a buffer array.
The RAW file has blocks of 512 bytes each so the array is 512 in size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long int findSize(FILE *file);

int buffer[512];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    long int size = findSize(file);
    int blocks = size/512;
    int counts = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
    {
        while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, file) == 512)
        {
            printf("%i\n", buffer[counts]);
            counts++;
        }
    }
}


long int findSize(FILE *file)
{
    // checking if the file exist or not
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File Not Found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);

    // calculating the size of the file
    long int res = ftell(file);

    // closing the file
    fclose(file);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is `printf("%i\n", buffer[counts])` supposed to do? After the 512th block this is exceeding the array bounds. And, the code overwrites the same buffer without doing anything with its content. I also recommend specifically stating `"rt"` or `"rb"` for the read mode, in general.

Comment: The main fault is reading from a closed file, but the two nested loops is also quite wrong. Use a *single* loop, controlled by the `fread`, not a theoretical value. One loop, e.g. `while ((n= fread(buffer, 1, 512, file)) != 0) { /* store(n); */  counts++; }`

Comment: The `int blocks = size/512;` only works if it the size is an exact multiple of 512. otherwise use `int blocks = 1 + (size - 1) /512;`

Comment: You should probably check for remainder - ie remainder = size % 512; and if so you don't have an exact multiple of 512 eg remainder != 0.  You hsould not go into loop if file is null

Comment: @AngusComber I have checked the file for null while checking its size so that's not an issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know that the file size will be a multiple of 512. So that's not an issue too.

Comment: @WeatherVane Your solution and the answer given below both have helped remove the segmentation fault. The problem was probably reading from a closed file. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function *findSize* you shouldn't close the file but rewind it:

```
// fclose(file);
rewind(file);
```